# How to simplyfy this function with linq-to-xml query?

Tags: linq-to-xml, where-clause

I have read all or almost everything tags linq-to-xml to find a correct use of where clause in my routine... but I'm not able to find a solution...
Anyone can help me, please ?

Following my ugly code...

```
    public string ExtractTag(string fileName, string tagName)
    {
        string fileBuffer = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            fileBuffer = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(fileBuffer);
        //Debug.WriteLine("doc.DescendantNodes().Count()=" + doc.DescendantNodes().Count());

        foreach (XNode node in doc.DescendantNodes())
        {
            if (node is XElement)
            {
                XElement element = (XElement)node;
                // Search the root node
                if (element.Name.LocalName.Equals("FatturaElettronica"))
                {
                    // Enumerate all nodes of "FatturaElettronica"
                    IEnumerable<XElement> de = from el in element.Descendants() select el;
                    foreach (XElement el in de)
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(el.Name.ToString(), tagName) == 0)
                        {
                            return el.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Does your current code work?  Is there a performance issue?  Can you share a full [mcve] showing XML for which the current code is not performing as required?  Why are you checking just the local name and not the namespace as well?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are happy with the results of your code and searching for first Descendant of FatturaElettronica with the given name (if it exists). You could write that in different and shorter ways. ie:

```
public string ExtractTag(string fileName, string tagName)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    var node = doc
        .Descendants("FatturaElettronica")
        .Descendants(tagName)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return node == null ? string.Empty : node.Value;
}
```

Or you might choose to use a much shorter XPath approach (I would send FatturaElettronica as the parameter rather than hardcoding):

```
//Sample call
var result = ExtractTag(@"c:\folder\myfile.xml", "//FatturaElettronica//id"); 

public string ExtractTag(string fileName, string xpath)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    var node = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
    return node == null ? string.Empty : node.Value;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! You understand my needs! I prefer the first solution because I will find "Fattura Elettronica" in all documents...
Thanks a lot...